# CSS dropdown menu to stay visible when hovering over list items?

Tags: css, hover, dropdown

Working on a website (inherited someone else's code) and I'm trying to make a dropdown menu. The dropdown appears correctly when I hover over the item, but as soon as I mouse down to the dropdown list items, they disappear. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong here?

```css
#nav {
 position:fixed;
 top: -1em;
 background: #000;
 font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 width:100%;
 text-align:right;
 padding: 1.25em;
 z-index: 3;
}
#nav li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0em 0.25em;
 color: #90918F;
} 
#nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0em 0.5em;
 margin: 0;
 color: #90918F;
}
#nav li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #90918F;
}
#nav li a.active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #90918F;
}
#nav li.space {
 padding: 2em;
} 
ul {
 padding: 0.05em;

}
#nav ul {
 z-index: 3;
 margin-top: 0;
 background: #000;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 72px;
 right: 450px; 
}
#nav ul li {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.75em;
 text-align: left;
 
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
#nav li > ul:hover {
 position: absolute !important;
}
#nav ul li:after {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
    top: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
}
```

```html
 <ul id="nav">
  <div id="logo">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
   <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#values">Values</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team">Our Team</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#employment">STUDENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Works fine for me (ABOUT item).

Comment: @Gerard It's interesting that it works here but not on the actual site. Can you think of anything that might cause this?